# How can I change the appearance of the mouse cursor in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, mouse

How can I change the mouse a cursor to a picture using libGDX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### v1.7.0+

```
Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("cursorImage.png"));
Gdx.graphics.setCursor(Gdx.graphics.newCursor(pm, 0, 0));
pm.dispose();
```

#### Before v1.7.0

```
Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("cursorImage.png"));
Gdx.input.setCursorImage(pm, 0, 0);
pm.dispose();
```

The hotspot parameters represent the "tip" of the cursor. For example, the operating system cursor has the hotspot at the top-left corner, but a crosshair cursor might have the hotspot at its center.

Comment: Thank you! Well but I have a problem the method Gdx.input.setCursorImage(image, xPos, y Pos); give this error The method setCursorImage(Pixmap, int, int) is undefined for the type Input

Comment: Well the function [certainly exists](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.java#L778), but it was added [a year ago this month](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/0f81b9170c065a11666022dfa742a5292aec821a#diff-3bf70c039a3794f4a60755e575ddcc49), so make sure you're using the latest version of libgdx. If you are and you're still getting that error, then I don't think I can help.

Comment: Gdx.graphics.setCursor(Gdx.graphics.newCursor(pm,0,0,));

Comment: Is it worth keeping the pixmap in case I change often ?